# Resize image within HTML5 Canvas to fit any monitor in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have an image that covers the entire width and height of a canvas that covers the entire screen. The problem is, when the code is run on a computer with a different resolution (width and height), the image does not adjust to the proper height and width of that screen. It stays the original size that I set it in JS. I'm very new to JavaScript, so any help I could get to this image to resize on different resolutions would be amazing. Thanks!

```js
//Global Canvas

var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas1');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Functions

function load_image1() {
 "use strict";
 var base_image;
 base_image = new Image();
 base_image.src = ['https://postimg.cc/tnGDb1vD'];
 
 base_image.onload = function(){
    c.drawImage(base_image, (window.innerWidth - 1700), -100, 1920, 1080);
};
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 margin: 0; 
}

.canvas1 {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Sylvanas</title>
 
 <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 
 <canvas class="canvas1">
 </canvas>
 <!--<canvas class="canvas2">
 </canvas>-->

 <script src="script.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your code. We have no idea what you are already using or implementing. There is nothing for us to go on.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't mean to hit submit yet without adding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust some `c.drawImage()` params to get what you're after using some `window` properties.

Edit: As pointed out in a comment below I added some additional code to listen for a window resize which will adjust the dimensions of the canvas image as needed. This solution does flash a bit on my screen when resizing so there is a potential drawback.

```
c.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gucr5m1b/4/

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas1');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function load_image1() {
 "use strict";
 var base_image = new Image();
 base_image.src = ['http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg'];
 base_image.onload = function() {
    c.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 };
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  load_image1();
}

function startCanvas() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  resizeCanvas();
}

startCanvas();
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 margin: 0; 
}

.canvas1 {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's not super clear from the post, but I think the OP wants the canvas to fit the screen on window resize as well (it would make sense.) I'd add that bit.

Comment: @wahwahwah Good Point. I'll check into that and add that to the answer.